# Programmatically reverse Storyboard

Tags: wpf, storyboard

I have the following storyboard:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="ButtonsAnim">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="topRightButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2000000" Value="-100"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="topRightButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2000000" Value="100"/>
...
```

It basically moves some buttons around in a canvas.

This is the code that starts the animation:

```
void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Storyboard sb = (Storyboard)Resources["ButtonsAnim"];
    storyBoard = sb;
    storyBoard.Begin(this, true);

}
```

What I am trying to do is to reset the animation when I click a button which hides the window. When the window reappears the animation should start from the beginning.

I tried using storyBoard.Begin(this, true) when the application reappears but for this first milliseconds the buttons are at their last position.

I then tried storyBoard.seek(TimeSpan.Zero) before hiding the window but it fails:

> System.Windows.Media.Animation
>   Warning: 6 : Unable to perform action
>   because the specified Storyboard was
>   never applied to this object for
>   interactive control.; Action='Seek';
>   Storyboard='System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard';
>   Storyboard.HashCode='24901833';
>   Storyboard.Type='System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard';
>   TargetElement='System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard';
>   TargetElement.HashCode='24901833';
>   TargetElement.Type='System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard'

I also tried storyBoard.remove(this) before hiding the window, same effect: the buttons are at their last position.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To use `StoryBoard.Remove()` this way - you should keep reference to your storyboard object.

Like this:

```
Storyboard myStoryBoard; 

void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myStoryBoard = (Storyboard)Resources["myStoryBoard"];
    myStoryBoard.Begin();

}

void sbRemoveEvent()
{
    myStoryBoard.Remove();  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `Storyboard.Stop()` should work here. But if you not find anything elegant, you can try reset buttons' transform after you've hided the window. E.g.:

```
((TranslateTransform)((TransformGroup)topRightButton.RenderTransform)[3]).X = 0;
((TranslateTransform)((TransformGroup)topRightButton.RenderTransform)[3]).Y = 0;
```

Hope I didn't make any mistake while casting.

NB: You may also find useful this example from MSDN: [How to: Control a Storyboard After It Starts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741997.aspx)

Comment: Stop does reverse the effect of the animation -- but apparently it does it instantly, rather than animating it in reverse.